# jQuery $.getJSON not working but on thaicreate.com working

Tags: jquery, getjson

http://www.thaicreate.com/jquery/jquery-ajax-jquery-getjson.html

http://www.thaicreate.com/jQuery-Demo/jQuerygetJSON.html

This code not working? why?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
      <title>ThaiCreate.Com jQuery Tutorials</title>
      <script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://www.thaicreate.com/jQuery-Demo/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function () {

            $("#btn1").click(function () {

               $.getJSON("http://www.thaicreate.com/jQuery-Demo/json.js", function (result) {
                  $.each(result, function (i, field) {
                     $("#div1").append(field + "<br / >");
                  });
               });

            });

         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="div1"></div>
      <input id="btn1" value="Load" type="button">
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It worked for me in Chrome 18. EDIT: Now, I see you changed the URL in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use an `absolute path` in the URL field because that request is `cross-domain`. It would need to include a `dataType` of `JSONP` for this purpose. It would be easier to copy the json.js file to your local disk.